# webpack 4 library target umd x is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

i have this es6 class in my /src/index.js

```
class Point {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    toString() {
        return `(${this.x}, ${this.y})`;
    }
}

export default Point;
```

here is the webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    library: 'point',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```

so when i include in my index.html file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Webpack</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        new point(1, 3).toString()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

so i have this error in console

> "Uncaught TypeError: point is not a constructor"

this is umd script type

why i'm seeing this error while compile with webpack?

same scenario working fine with rollup

is there any solution?

and one more thing i saw almost every developer use rollup for es6 package development to compile "esm", "umd" versions of the script.

but i want to use webpack instead of rollup.

any guide?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please add `libraryExport: 'default'`, in `output` section of Webpack configuration.

something like this (for your case),

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    library: 'point',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    libraryExport: 'default',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};
```