# TypeError: _API.default is not a constructor with Jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, expo

I have an API class that I am trying to use in a React app.

```
// API file

class API {
...
}

export default API;

// Other file
import API from "utils/API";

const api = new API();
```

And I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: _API.default is not a constructor
```

But.. it seems like my default is set?

My Jest setup is like this:

```
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetupFile.js"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg|react-router-native/.*|@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication/.*)"
    ]
  },
```

My **strong** guess is that this is due to a configuration of my babel, webpack or package.json.

What could be causing this?

Note, I want to be clear, this doesn't happen whatsoever in my main application, **only** in Jest testing

---

If I change it to a named export/import, I get this:

```
TypeError: _API.API is not a constructor
```

**Extremely** confusing behavior.

Comment: What happens if you change the `export` line to `export {API as default};`? Or respectively, if you put the `export default` right in front of the class definition?

Comment: may be this [link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5023) could help

Comment: @Markus - same error for both formats

Comment: @Darkcheftar Interesting. That IS the exact error I'm seeing, but I am not trying to mock this class at all. I wonder if there's some relationship between this error and anything I can glean from that links. Thanks, I'll at least check it out.

Comment: Please also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683089/webpack-4-library-target-umd-x-is-not-a-constructor)!

Comment: @Markus Thanks, I'll take a look. My best guess right now is either something to do with webpack or babel that's causing issues

Comment: If all these hints don’t help you should try to trim your issue to a minimal working example (code and setup) for us to reproduce.

Comment: Does the test works if you change the import from `"utils/API"` to `"../path/to/utils/API"`, if so, it's probably missing some babel-plugin-module-resolver, or jest moduleMapper to map the alias

Comment: @RoniCastro Nope, I thought that might have been it and tried it already. I'm drawing a complete blank here at this point. I'll try to put up a minimally reproduceable example sometime soon, but I basically have to spin up a new Expo app to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was ultimately due to additional code inside the file that I was exporting the class from.

```
import { store } from "root/App";

if (typeof store !== "undefined") {
  let storeState = store.getState();
  let profile = storeState.profile;
}
```

At the top, outside my class for some functionality I had been working on.

This caused the class default export to fail, but **only** in Jest, not in my actual application.

Comment: Thank you! I was seeing the same problem and with this tip, I was able to find a stray `export` after my class that was causing it.

Comment: I would upvote this, except it doesn't identify the cause. In my code this is definitely what's happening - module A imports B, which imports C, which imports D, which imports E, which instantiates a class X (which is not used in module A) which instantiates another class Y, but Y "is not a constructor" inside Jest tests. It would be difficult to avoid importing B (or otherwise avoid importing E) and there is no apparent reason why Y "is not a constructor" inside Jest.

Answer (score 17):

As mentioned by others, it would be helpful to see a minimum reproducible example.

However, there is one other possible cause. Are you mocking the API class in your test file at all? This problem can sometimes happen if a class is mistakenly mocked as an "object" as opposed to a function. An object cannot be instantiated with a "new" operator.

For example, say we have a class file `utils/API` like so:

```js
class API {
  someMethod() {
    // Does stuff
  }
}

export default API;
```

The following is an "incorrect" way to mock this class and will throw a `TypeError... is not a constructor` error if the class is instantiated after the mock has been created.

```js
import API from 'utils/API';

jest.mock('utils/API', () => {
  // Returns an object
  return {
    someMethod: () => {}
  };
})

// This will throw the error
const api = new API();
```

The following will mock the class as a function and will accept the `new` operator and will not throw the error.

```js
import API from 'utils/API';

jest.mock('utils/API', () => {
  // Returns a function
  return jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    someMethod: () => {}
  }));
})

// This will not throw an error anymore
const api = new API();
```

Comment: I answered this already, I found the solution/issue

Comment: Ah cool, I missed that. Very interesting that it could cause that issue. As you mentioned, it's probably something funky going on with babel or webpack. Glad you solved it though!

Answer (score 7):

Trying adding `"esModuleInterop": true,` in your `tsconfig.json`. BY default `esModuleInterop` is set to false or is not set. B setting esModuleInterop to true changes the behavior of the compiler and fixes some ES6 syntax errors.
Refer the documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop).

Comment: It was already set to true in my tsconfig.json

Comment: Plus all of the particular files involved are JS. I am converting my codebase over to TS, but only about halfway done, and none of these files have been done yet

Comment: So, your half project is `js` and other half is `ts`, then convert your code base completely to `ts` as there may be many conflicts. Then try delete the `node_modules` and reinstall it, then try testing the code.

Answer (score 5):

I'm adding this because the issue I had presented the same but has a slightly different setup.

I'm not exporting the class with default, i.e.

MyClass.ts

```
// with default
export default MyClass {
   public myMethod()
   {
      return 'result';
   }
}

// without default, which i'm doing in some instances.
export MyClass {
   public myMethod()
   {
      return 'result';
   }
}
```

When you don't have the default, the import syntax changes.

In a (jest) test if you follow the convention where you do have `export default MyClass(){};`

then the following works.

```
const MOCKED_METHOD_RESULT = 'test-result'
jest.mock("MyClass.ts", () => {
    // will work and let you check for constructor calls:
    return jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
        return {
            myMethod: () => {
                return MOCKED_METHOD_RESULT;
            },
   
        };
    });
});
```

However, if you don't have the `default` and or are trying to mock other classes etc. then you need to do the following.

Note, that the `{get MyClass(){}}` is the critical part, i believe you can swap out the `jest.fn().mockImplementation()` in favour of `jest.fn(()=>{})`

```
jest.mock("MyClass.ts", () => ({
    get MyClass() {
        return jest.fn().mockImplementation(function () {
            return {
               myMethod: () => {
                   return MOCKED_METHOD_RESULT;
               },
   
           };
        });
    },
}));
```

So the issue is the way in which you access the contents of the class your mocking. And the `get` part allows you to properly define class exports.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to export it like this :

```
export default class API
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything, same error

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by cyclic dependencies among modules. Here's an example based on real-life experience.

Suppose you define a data store for book information, with some caches to hold information and API classes for loading from the backend:

```
// Data.ts
import { Author, AuthorApi } from './Author';
import { Book, BookApi } from './Book';

class Data {
    books = new Cache<Book>(new BookApi());
    authors = new Cache<Author>(new AuthorApi());
}

// (In real life I'd install MobX for reactivity here)
class Cache<T> {
    constructor(public api: any) {}
    items: T[];
    //
    // ... other stuff ...
    //
}

export default new Data();
```

And we define `Author` and `Book` modules like this:

```
// Author.ts ----------------------------------------------------
export class Author {
    public constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}
}

export class AuthorApi { } // doesn't matter what's in here

// Book.ts ------------------------------------------------------
import data from './Data';

export class Book {
    constructor(public authorId: number, public title: string, public publishYear: number) { }

    get author() { return data.authors.items.filter(a => a.id === this.authorId)[0]; }
}

export class BookApi { } // doesn't matter what's in here
```

Here there is a circular reference between Book and Data. In the main app we start off with `import data from 'Data'` and it works fine. But in our unit tests we start with `import { Book } from 'Book'` (or some other module that uses `Book`) and get this error:

```
 TypeError: _Book.BookApi is not a constructor

      3 |
      4 | class Data {
    > 5 |     books = new Cache<Book>(new BookApi());
        |                             ^
      6 |     authors = new Cache<Author>(new AuthorApi());
      7 | }
      8 |
```

This happens because when importing 'Data', 'Data' imports 'Book', but 'Book' is *already being imported* and *has not finished being imported yet*. Book.ts cannot be processed a second time, so Data.ts is processed before Book.ts is fully initialized, so `BookApi` doesn't exist yet when the error occurs.

A simple workaround is to `import data from 'Data'` before importing `Book` in the tests. In TypeScript, by default, this workaround only works if `data` is used in the tests somewhere (e.g. `let _ = data;`). A much better solution is to find a way to eliminate the cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with:

*utils/API.js*

```
export default class API {
...
}
```

*test.js*

```
import API from "utils/API";

const api = new API();
```

Comment: Nope, no change. And it's so weird, because the code I have works perfectly in actual usage, but ONLY when I am trying to run "npm run test" does it fail.

Comment: Sorry @StevenMatthews , could you please provide us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It could help a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by using below code.

```
jest.mock('YOUR_API_PATH', () => ({
 __esModule: true,
 default: // REPLICATE YOUR API CONSTRUCTOR BEHAVIOUR HERE BY ADDING CLASS
})
```

If you want to mock complete API class, please check the below snippet.

```
jest.mock('YOUR_API_PATH', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: class {
    constructor(args) {
     this.var1 = args.var1
    }
    someMethod: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
  },
}));
```