# TypeError: class is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I have an issue where my tests are not running due to the following type error:

```
TypeError: _ViewStore.default is not a constructor
```

The app itself runs fine and I am assuming that the test cannot get the `JourneyStore` variable as it is used in the `setCurrentPageFromJourney` method of the `ViewStore` class.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

The view store class:

```
class ViewStore {
  currentPage: Stage;
  previousPageHistory: Stage[];

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
    this.currentPage = PDP_VIEWS.DEVICE;
    this.previousPageHistory = [];
  }

  set setCurrentPage(page: Stage) {
    this.currentPage = page;
    this.previousPageHistory.push(page);
    this.previousPageHistory = [...new Set(this.previousPageHistory)]; // removes duplicates
  }

  hasVisitedPage(page: Stage): boolean {
    return this.previousPageHistory.includes(page);
  }

  setCurrentPageFromJourney() {
    const journeyState = JourneyStore.journeyParams.state; // test passes if JourneyStore is not used (but then the app breaks)

    switch (journeyState) {
      case `a`:
        this.setCurrentPage = PDP_VIEWS.DEVICE;
        break;
      case `b`:
        this.setCurrentPage = PDP_VIEWS.INSURANCE;
        break;
    }
  }
}

export default ViewStore;
```

In another file, the view store (and others, including the journey store) is instantiated like this:

```
import ViewStoreClass from './ViewStore';
const ViewStore = new ViewStoreClass();
```

I think the app uses Mobx which I am unfamiliar with and do not know whether that would make any difference.

The test:

```
describe('ViewStore', () => {
  let store = new ViewStore();

  test('should pass', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })
});
```

By the way, the `JourneyStore` is just another class, with lots of properties and methods - I would show it but it will be a lot of code, and I think that may be all you need to know about it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: *"In another file, the view store (and others, including the journey store) is instantiated like this:"* That's very odd, using the class name as the name of a constant with an **instance** of the class. *"The test:"* How are you importing `ViewStore` there? If it's like the other file, that's the problem, you'd need `new ViewStoreClass()` rather than `new ViewStore()` (or, much better, don't do the weird thing of using `ViewStore` as the name of a constant that refers to just an *instance* of the class :-) ).

Comment: It's just imported in the test file as `import ViewStore from './ViewStore';` - but doing it like `import ViewStoreClass from './ViewStore';` and `let store = new ViewStoreClass();` seems to have the same result

Comment: `import ViewStore from './ViewStore';` is correct for how you're exporting the class (assuming your bundler allows missing extensions, as some do), so at least from an ESM perspective, the code is correct. That means it's a bundler and/or Jest issue, so it would be useful to post your Jest setup and bundler information.

Comment: Did you try the solutions mentioned in this SO thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889648/typeerror-api-default-is-not-a-constructor-with-jest-tests

Comment: Thank you all. It turns out that I had to pass in the journey store as an argument when creating a view store instance and make the constructor use it in order to solve this